# How do I add an element to a SSJS array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, xpages

I'm writing to an author and then a reader field. My author field is correct and uses the array, but when I try to add one or more values to that array, it writes the integer 10 to the reader field. What am I doing wrong?

```
if (document1.isNewNote()) {
var docBackEnd:NotesDocument = document1.getDocument(true);
var a = new Array();
a[0] = getComponent('AuthorCN').getValue();
a[1] = document1.getItemValue("Super_Name")[0];
a[2] = document1.getItemValue("Holder_Name")[0];
a[3] = document1.getItemValue("AppName")[0];
a[4] = document1.getItemValue("OrderName")[0];
a[5] = document1.getItemValue("CertBy")[0];
a[6] = "Lab Access";
a[7] = "Warehouse";
a[8] = "[Admin]";



var item:NotesItem = docBackEnd.replaceItemValue('FormEditors',  @Unique(a));
item.setAuthors(true);

item = docBackEnd.replaceItemValue('FormReaders', @Unique(a.push('Another array value')));
item.setReaders(true);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'd recommend to follow Fredrik's modifications to your code, the *real* problem lies in your usage of the array's "push" method: it adds a new element to an array, returning its new length, but **not** the array itself. So in your case '10' indeed is the correct return value.

All you need to do is to perform the array extension and the field assignment parts in separate steps:

1:

```
a.push('Another array value');
```

2:

```
item = docBackEnd.replaceItemValue('FormReaders', @Unique(a));
item.setReaders(true);
```

Also see: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: item.recyle(); - for lazy people var a= []; a[a.length] = newValue; even a[newValue]=newValue would work. Eliminates the duplicate issue.

Comment: Ok. I got it working  by doing what Lothar Mueller and the others said. Now, I'm trying to use a @DbLookup to populate the array, but I keep getting an error. Isn't the @DbLookup returning an array if there are multiple values in it?
`
db = new Array("NatickNotes02", "myfolder\\mydb.nsf")
dir = getComponent("Dir").value;
div = getComponent("Div").value;

lu = @DbLookup(db, "ManagerAccess", dir + "PP" + div, "DTManagers");
var a = [];
a.push(lu);
 
var item:NotesItem = docBackEnd.replaceItemValue('FormReaders', @Unique(a));
item.setReaders(true);`

Comment: @m benway: please start a new question for this one so that it can easily be found and answered. It also will be much easier to read and comprehend as formatting of comments is rather poor as you see.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the code like this to add the entries to the array

```
var a = [] // att better way that new Array()
a.push(getComponent('AuthorCN').getValue());
a.push(document1.getItemValue("Super_Name")[0]);
a.push(document1.getItemValue("Holder_Name")[0]);
a.push(document1.getItemValue("AppName")[0]);
a.push(document1.getItemValue("OrderName")[0]);
a.push(document1.getItemValue("CertBy")[0]);
a.push("Lab Access");
a.push("Warehouse");
a.push("[Admin]");
var item:NotesItem = docBackEnd.replaceItemValue('FormEditors',  @Unique(a));
item.setAuthors(true);

item = docBackEnd.replaceItemValue('FormReaders', @Unique(a.push('Another array value')));
item.setReaders(true);
```

Comment: I would also recommend `var a = [ ];` instead of `var a = new Array();`

Comment: Here's a full explanation of why: http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-9AN5ZK

Comment: I have made those changes, double checked it, and did several tests. The results are the same. It's writing the number 10 as the value of the 'FormReaders' field.
This script runs on the xpage's querySaveDocument event. The "FormEditors" field type and values are perfectly fine.

Comment: Also, I have another question: do I even need to have the people/groups/roles that I have in the FormEditors field to also be in FormReaders field. Wouldn't that list of users already have reader access to the document?